# The SSD not showing up correctly in diskutil in recovery

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd, recovery

I’ve deleted my Macintosh HD partition and don't know what to do, because the free space isn't showing up in the graphic interface of `diskutil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did manage to format it via the command `diskutil addPartition disk0s1 %Apple_APFS% %noformat% 0` (even though I had `disk0s1` and I needed to create a partition under that section, it understood what I wanted to do and created for me `disk0s2`) and I did manage to get my Macintosh HD back.

As I didn’t find anything useful for this situation on the web, I wanted to share my little experience here :)

Comment: After entering the command given in your answer, did you need to use the Disk Utility to erase `disk0s2` using the name `Macintosh HD` and format `APFS`? Or, maybe you did something else?

Comment: Yes after adding the partition you need to rename it if you want or just you can type name after %noformat% you can see it [here](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html)